# How to implement "software interrupt"?

Tags: python, interrupt, exit, break

I am trying to create an "emergency stop" button that will immediately stop / break a linear code execution, but I am unable to come up with a solution. We have a GUI running in a browser and when a button is pushed an MQTT messages is received by the back end (which is written by me in Python).
There are different threads and the message is received, but when in another thread an if statement is running I am unable to figure out how to stop / break the linear code execution in that thread right away. Is there a good method for this?
It would be also OK if I could stop the entire thread and afterwards start it again (if another button is pushed). How could I do that?
I mean. I could probably solve this right away if I would be using a hardware switch and an interrupt (the code is running on a Raspberry Pi by the way). But I do not know how to "simulate" an interrupt and an interrupt service routing in a software. I most definitely can't be the only person facing the same problem.

Comment: You can try to look at signal module .

Comment: Are you required to truly break the thread's execution at whatever it's doing at that moment? Can you explain your real use case a bit more concretely?

Comment: Either way: a full emergency stop: send a `SIGKILL` to your Python process.